# 4D Matrix operation in Python - conversion from MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, dynamic-programming, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to translate this MATLAB code to Python:

MATLAB:  `V_c = delta* max(V_L, repmat(V_A_c,[N_p 1]) - NM )`

where these are 4D arrays:

`V_c` is the continuation value for in different states, (should have shape 81, 75, 15, 31)
`V_L` is the initial value, (has shapes 81, 75, 15, 31)
`V_A_c` is the value of adjustment under optimal choice (has shape 1, 75, 15, 31)

`NM` is a number (`NM = κ*np.exp(P0)`)
`N_p` is the length of the grid

This is my attempted python code

PYTHON:  `V_c = delta * np.amax(V_L,(np.tile(V_A_c,(([N_p,1]))))-NM)`

I get errors, that the lengths of the arrays are different, and that only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

In Python, my `V_L` and `V_A_c` has the same values and shapes as the MATLAB gives, but I still can't compute V_c. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you mention, comes from the fact that you want to element-wise compare two tensor (matrix). use np.maximum.

considering the tile operation is correct and N_p is 85 in you example:

```
V_c = delta * np.maximum(V_L, np.tile(V_A_c,(N_p,1,1,1)) - NM )
```

Comment: you are very welcome, accept then as answer and vote !